# WebKit: flexbox without <DOCTYPE>?

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox

Is is possible to use **flexbox** on WebKit without declaring a `<DOCTYPE>`?

My project is constrained: I can modify CSS but I need to preserve existing HTML as much as possible, which does not include a `<DOCTYPE>`.  Adding in flexbox declarations works on Firefox, but not Chrome/Safari.

#### Clarification

I am dealing with a very old codebase.  I can modify HTML in place, but it is generally a bad idea in this situation.  In testing, adding a `DOCTYPE` breaks *way more* than flexbox fixes.

*(This seems like a basic question, but I can't seem to find this answer anywhere.)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it neccessary to add HTML doctype at the starting of the web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595073/is-it-neccessary-to-add-html-doctype-at-the-starting-of-the-web-page)

Comment: See here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18373091/3597276

Comment: When you omit the `<doctype>` the browser will go into *quirks mode*. For modern code, it's always better to have browsers render in *standards mode*.

Comment: @Michael_B that addresses why I _should_ include a `DOCTYPE` but I _can't_ include one.

Comment: @ManojKumar I would certainly appreciate an example of flexbox working in Chrome without a `DOCTYPE`, but keep in mind that JSFiddle et al include a `DOCTYPE` for you.

Comment: When a document is rendered in quirks mode the results can be unpredictable and unreliable. You really can't be sure what you're doing to get.

Comment: Check out this example: http://i.imgur.com/PSODR9r.jpg I tried on my local server

Comment: @Michael_B correct.  Very unpredictable indeed.  Except that the unpredictable behavior is what people have become to expect for the last 10 years.  I need to make only the most minor of edits to prevent a lot of unintended consequences.

Comment: Then I guess you have a lot of testing ahead. You'll have to see how flexbox behaves in quirks mode on Chrome, FF, IE, Safari, mobile, etc.

Comment: @ManojKumar Chrome may be deciding against Quirks mode due to the cleanliness of the code and so allowing flexbox.

Comment: @Michael_B yeah, that's my problem.  It appears WebKit does not honor flexbox declarations in Quirks mode.  I was asking the question to see if there are known work-arounds to force the behavior.

Comment: If you *must* omit the `DOCTYPE` and you *must* use flexbox, that's a tough obstacle. Probably insurmountable IMO. If there's any flexibility with either one, the odds are better.

Comment: @Michael_B I have an ugly solution with `position` that works but may be brittle.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex and it will work on chrome as well.

For checking any property you can take help from the below site:
caniuse.com
http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Please add explantion also not just the link

Comment: This does not address the question.  I was specifically asking about `DOCTYPE`.